# Excel Workbook to PDF Macro Error

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

The following code generates an invoice number sequence where every time I open the template it keeps a record of what invoice no. I'm up to:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim RefNo As Long
Dim Folder As String
Dim SheetNum As Integer
Dim IndexSheet As String
Dim FilePrefix As String
Dim FileSuffix As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Folder = "C:\Users\Desktop\"
FilePrefix = "Invoice#" & " "
FileSuffix = " " & "(DRAFT)"


RefNo = Sheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").Value

'Increment the Reference number
Sheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").Value = RefNo + 1

'Write new Ref No to sheet
Range("ThisIndex").Value = RefNo

'Save this workbook
ThisWorkbook.Save

'Create a new workbook with just 1 sheet
Workbooks.Add (1)

'Copy sheets from template to new workbook

For SheetNum = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum)

Next


'Blank the Next Ref No so it doesn't get saved in the new workbook/sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").ClearContents

'Delete default sheet from new workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'Select Info sheet to make it active
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice1").Select

'Save workbook with the new Reference Number name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Folder & FilePrefix & RefNo & FileSuffix & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Close the template workbook
ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

However, when I add the following macro, It creates another file from the template

```
Sub SavePDF()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:="C:\PDF\Export.pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

For example, when I open the template with the above code, and I run the macro assigned to saving the file to PDF, it will save it as PDF but it will create another template file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Source from: http://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/macro-enabled-excel-templates

Comment: Try a slight mod to Sub SavePDF to pass in a Range rather using ActiveSheet

Comment: I've tried that but the same error keeps occurring. The problem I believe to be is that whenever I create another macro and run it, it calls the Private Sub Workbook_Open(). Any ideas?

Comment: Where is Sub SavePDF stored and how/from where is this called?

Comment: Apologies for not being explicit enough, the Sub SavePDF is stored in the "ThisWorkbook" workspace along with the Private Sub Workbook_Open(). The Sub SavePDF is assigned to a Button, so when the button is clicked, it will save it as PDF.

Comment: Er.. and where is the Button located?

Comment: Looking again, I don't think it is creating a new template file, I think it is probably opening the existing template file to get access to the SavePDF macro.

Comment: Possibly, any ideas on how I can fix this

Comment: So where is the button located and as a matter of interest what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2010, the button is located in on the Sheet "Invoice". The tempalte file has the button next to the invoice template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK @delc I have a solution for you but it is not particularly elegant.  The issue is to de-couple 'Sub SavePDF' from the Invoice Template file.  This solution puts this Sub in the newly created Invoice WorkBook. So the biggest downside is that the new Invoice workbook will itself be a macro-enabled workbook! Note that I have adjusted the .pdf output to Page 1 only, so that the button and named range cells don't get copied to the .pdf file. You can change this if desired in the second piece of code.  You will see that I have also renamed 'Sub SavePDF'.

Referring to the Invoice Template workbook:

Replace your button on the 'Invoice1' sheet with a shape and call it **PDF** (Edit Text).

Replace your current code in the **ThisWorkBook** module with the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim RefNo As Long
Dim Folder As String
Dim SheetNum As Integer
Dim IndexSheet As String
Dim FilePrefix As String
Dim FileSuffix As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Folder = "C:\Users\Desktop\"
FilePrefix = "Invoice#" & " "
FileSuffix = " " & "(DRAFT)"


RefNo = Sheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").Value

'Increment the Reference number
Sheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").Value = RefNo + 1

'Write new Ref No to sheet
Range("ThisIndex").Value = RefNo

'Save this workbook
ThisWorkbook.Save

'Create a new workbook with just 1 sheet
Workbooks.Add (1)

'Copy sheets from template to new workbook
    For SheetNum = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum).Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNum)
    Next

'Blank the Next Ref No so it doesn't get saved in the new workbook/sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice1").Range("NextIndex").ClearContents

'Assign macro to button
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice1").Shapes("PDF").Select
Selection.OnAction = ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!Sheet1.PDF_Click"

'Delete default sheet from new workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Select Info sheet to make it active
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice1").Select

'Save workbook with the new Reference Number name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Folder & FilePrefix & RefNo & FileSuffix & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Close the template workbook
ThisWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

In the **Sheet1** module put the following code:

```
Sub PDF_Click()

Sheets("Invoice1").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Export.pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False, From:=1, To:=1

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Save it and run it!

Other options may be to make 'Sub SavePDF' as a UDF and actioned with a key-combination or put a button on the Excel Ribbon to run it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @barryleajo! The above code works great